# Can't launch Youtube API sample Demo, requires YouTube App

Tags: android, api, youtube

I was successful in getting the Youtube API demo to launch from eclipse.  However when i tried to initiate a demo it states: "This app won't run without the YouTube App, which is missing from your device."

I am running the android emulator so it does not come with the youtube app by default.

Has anyone experience this problem and what did you do to correct it?

Answer (score 6):

You need a physical device with the Youtube app installed to run the YouTubeAPIDemoActivity.

Comment: Yes thats so lame that you need a physical device, I had the same problem and your suggestion worked.